# Does comments affect when including files in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, include, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commenting interpreted code and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730948/commenting-interpreted-code-and-performance)

When you include a file in PHP with `include()` or any other function, its perfomance is affected by the amount of comments of the included file?

(I am not saying I am going to sacrifice legibility)

Comment: Very related (so much in fact I consider voting for "close as duplicate"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730948/commenting-interpreted-code-and-performance and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731022/do-comments-slow-down-an-interpreted-language

Comment: well, this is more related to the performance of inclusion functions in PHP

Comment: The effect of comments should be the same regardless of why the file is being parsed (i.e. regardless of whether it's run as "main file" of `include`ed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the savings of time required to parse the file is not even measurable (too small) and not worth slightest consideration. It's definitely not the bottleneck of performance, so to say.