# Is it possible to use preloader for cli script not for php-fpm?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, php-7.4, php-8

I understand what we could compile our PHP code to OpCache using preloader in 7.4. As I understand, it is only meant for CGI/FastCGI (PHP-FPM). Is it possible to do the same thing for just a CLI script that is not meant to be executed on HTTP request but console run?

Here I created a [small repository example](https://github.com/Legion112/preloader-example).

Answer (score 1):

Technically preloading works for CLI.

I didn't get your example to use it, though. I am not familiar with the PHP image you used but here are some pointers:

1. You should run your container as non-root (or configure a user for preloading), see https://www.php.net/manual/de/opcache.preloading.php ("Running preloading as root is not allowed.")

   You could add `user: <someUserId>:<someUsergroupId>` to your service. Depending on how user switching is implemented in PHP it might need an entry in `/etc/passwd`.
2. opcode cache for CLI is opt-in, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.enable-cli

Comment: I have googled about opcache.enable-cli https://stackoverflow.com/a/25047263/7921383
It seems to do nothing because OpCache is stored in memory.
Well, I found what we can configure to use a file instead of memory. But I wonder when the OpChaching will happen? On the first script run?

Answer (score 1):

There is [a page on Preloading in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.preloading.php) which explicitly mentions this scenario:

> Additionally, preloading is only useful when there is a persistent process from one request to another. That means while it can work in a CLI script if the opcache is enabled, it's generally pointless.

To enable it, you would set something like this in your php.ini:

```
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.file_cache=/some/dir/somewhere
opcache.file_cache_only=1
opcache.preload=/path/to/preload.php
```

If you configure this and run a CLI script, the preload script in `/path/to/preload.php` will be executed, and any use of include, include_once, require, require_once, or opcache_compile_file() will cause compiled opcodes to be stored in `/some/dir/somewhere`.

When you run a second CLI script, it will be able to use those compiled opcodes, but *it won't know that preloading has already happened*. As such, everything that you put in preload.php will run on every script load anyway. You would need to handle this manually, e.g. by calling [opcache_is_script_cached](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-is-script-cached.php).

The complexity of using it all this way probably exceeds the gain for most use cases.